# JavaScript edit-inplace-holders which work with Wiki sources

Tags: javascript, wiki-engine

I'd like to dynamicly parse in text wiki-content.
I found [JsWiki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jswiki) but its in beta form, and looks like with no community even developers). Any other?

Comment: For which wiki? MediaWiki or one of the many others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by wiki content. There are many wiki frameworks just as there are many formats for wiki text. If you're looking for something that parses mediawiki content, such as wikipedia, there's a [good list of parsers here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers). Some are Javascript based and I've had a good experience with one of them, [InstaView](https://github.com/cscott/instaview).

It may be that you're just looking for a form of simple markup, in which case you could try using a library like [ShowDown](http://attacklab.net/showdown/) instead.

Comment: InstaView is now available [on GitHub](https://github.com/cscott/instaview) and [on npm](https://npmjs.org/package/instaview).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Ra-Ajax InPlaceEdit](http://ra-ajax.org/samples/Ajax-InPlaceEdit.aspx) for such things if you're on ASP.NET. It doesn't have automated built in wiki parsing, but it allows for adding up any control you wish including LinkButtons and Literals which you can then build up with the HTML you want yourself...

Comment: Thanks, thats not what I am searching, but its really great idea, to work with wiki source on server, and send only html rendered.

Answer (score 0):

There is another beautiful Javascript (only) based wiki editor. I just loved the idea itself. Check it out [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com)